# How to assign an image output from one pipeline to another pipeline?

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter, pipeline

I have these two pipelines in my Jupyter notebook.

```
## Loading Diffusion Pipeline
from diffusers import DiffusionPipeline
import torch



##Image Generating


pipe = DiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0", torch_dtype=torch.float32, use_safetensors=True, variant="fp16")

pipe.unet = torch.compile(pipe.unet, mode="reduce-overhead", fullgraph=True)

# load both base & refiner
base = DiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(
    "stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0", torch_dtype=torch.float32, variant="fp16", use_safetensors=True
)
pipe.enable_model_cpu_offload 

refiner = DiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(
    "stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-refiner-1.0",
    text_encoder_2=base.text_encoder_2,
    vae=base.vae,
    torch_dtype=torch.float32,
    use_safetensors=True,
    variant="fp16",
)


# Define how many steps and what % of steps to be run on each experts (80/20) here
n_steps = 40
high_noise_frac = 0.8

prompt = "A man playing soccer in a stadium"

# run both experts
image = base(
    prompt=prompt,
    num_inference_steps=n_steps,
    denoising_end=high_noise_frac,
    output_type="latent",
).images
image = refiner(
    prompt=prompt,
    num_inference_steps=n_steps,
    denoising_start=high_noise_frac,
    image=image,
).images[0].show()

##Image Captioning
from transformers import pipeline

image_to_text = pipeline("image-to-text", model="nlpconnect/vit-gpt2-image-captioning")
image_to_text(image)
```

The first one is creating an image with stable diffusion xl-base and with the other one I want to get an image captioning of the created image.
How can I assign the generated image which is saved in the RAM to the image captioning pipeline?

Thanks!

I tried to put the "image" variable into the second pipeline put always received an error.

Comment: Can you give us the error message you received when you input the image in the second pipeline ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign the generated image to another DiffusionPipeline instance, you can create a new instance and pass the generated image to its images attribute.
Here’s an example of how to assign the generated image to another DiffusionPipeline instance:

```
from diffusers import DiffusionPipeline

repo_id = "./my-diffusion-pipeline"
new_pipe = DiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(repo_id, use_safetensors=True)
new_pipe.images = [image]
```

Note that the new DiffusionPipeline instance must have the same components (models, schedulers, and processors) as the original instance.

Then If you want to save the generated image to a directory, you can use the save() method of the PIL Image class.

```
image.save("my_image.png")
```

This will save the generated image to a file named my_image.png in the current working directory.